# derivatives of equation with matrix multiplication and element wise multiplication (Hadamard product)

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

suppose I have two 2-by-2 matrices X and W. I will use $@$ for matrix multiplication and $*$ for elementwise multiplication.

let $Z=X@W^T$ and $Y=sigmoid(Z)=\frac{1}{1+exp(-Z)}$ and the gradient of y to itself is a 2-by-2 matrix of 1's

By the help from this [website](https://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/) I have $\frac{\partial{Y}}{\partial{X}}=Y*(1-Y)@W$. Now how can I differentiate $\frac{\partial{Y}}{\partial{X}}$ again w.r.t. $X$? There's elementwise and matrix multiplications in it and I messed up every time using chain rule. Can someone help me using proper math? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the symbol $(\odot)$ to denote the elementwise/Hadamard product,
$(\otimes)$ to denote the Kronecker product,
and $(\cdot )$ to denote the standard matrix product.
$$\eqalign{
Z &= X\cdot W^T
 &\iff z = {\rm vec}(Z) = (W\otimes I)\cdot{\rm vec}(X) = M\cdot x \\
Y &= \sigma(Z)  &\iff y = {\rm vec}(Y) = \sigma(z) \\
A &= Y-Y\odot Y &\iff a = {\rm vec}(A)\;\;\;\iff\; D={\rm Diag}(a)\\
dY &= A\odot dZ \\
dy &= a\odot dz = D\cdot dz &\;\;=\;\; D\cdot M\cdot dx \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} &= D\cdot M &\iff\;
\boxed{\color{\red}{\;\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X} = \vec{\mu}\cdot D\cdot M\cdot\vec{\nu}}\;} \\
}$$
where the components of the third-order tensors $(\vec{\mu},\vec{\nu})$ in the final expression are given by
$$\eqalign{
{\vec\nu}_{\ell jk} &= \begin{cases}
1\quad{\rm if}\;\;\ell=j+2k-2 \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
\\
{\vec\mu}_{jk \ell} &= {\vec\nu}_{\ell jk} \\
}$$
and the index ranges are
$$\eqalign{
1&\le\; j,k  \;&\le 2, \qquad
1&\le\; \ell \;&\le 4 \\\\
}$$

---

An alternative approach (which avoid tensors) is to note that
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial X}{\partial X_{ij}} &= E_{ij} \\
}$$
where $E_{ij}$ is a matrix whose $(i,j)^{th}$ element equals one and all other elements equal zero.

Use this to calculate a component-wise gradient
$$\eqalign{
dY &= A\odot\Big(dX\cdot W^T\Big) \\
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X_{ij}}
 &= A\odot\Big(E_{ij}\cdot W^T\Big) \\
}$$